# How to find the inverse of a exponential function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The function is $f(x) = 3^{-x}$. I have tried by finding the inverse, i.e. $-\log_3x$, but I am not so sure.

Answer (score 2):

If $y = 3^{-x}$, you are correct that we can find $x$ by taking a base $3$ logarithm:

$$\log_3 y = \log_3 3^{-x} = -x \log_3 3 = -x$$

Or upon rearrangement, $x = -\log_3 y$. Hence the desired inverse function is $y = -\log_3(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

What you’ve done is fine. Starting with $y=3^{-x}$, you can take the log base $3$ of both sides to get $\log_3y=-x$, and solving for $x$ then gives you $x=-\log_3y$. Thus, $f^{-1}(x)=-\log_3x$, exactly as you thought.

Answer (score 1):

You can always check whether it is correct by exploiting the definition of inverse function, i.e. $\operatorname{f}(\operatorname{f}^{-1}(x))=\operatorname{f}^{-1}(\operatorname{f}(x))=x$.

In your case, $3^{-(-\log_{3}x)}=3^{\log_3{x}}=x$, so you are right.